# AjaxControlToolkit CalendarExtender Control not working in my website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, calendarextender

I' using the AjaxControlToolkit `CalendarExtender` in my web site but after uploading it does how show the calendar control. I have registered the control on the page itself. The page postback when I click the image on which I applied the control.

What can be the reason of this?

Comment: how about showing us some code?

Comment: Any javascript errors? I have had this problem sometimes and it had to do with the javascript not working (scriptmanager).

Answer (score 2):

Check whether you added ToolkitscriptManager in your page, which is in AjaxToolkit

Comment: what is the use of it and wht does it do

Comment: This enables the AJAX Control in your Page and to use in your page

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an `ImageButton` to show the calendar,
then use ajax control toolkit and put these controls

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
                     ImageUrl="calIcon.jpg" />
    <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="TextBox1" 
                          PopupButtonID="ImageButton1" runat="server">
        </asp:CalendarExtender>
```

If you are still getting the page postback when clicking the ImageButton, you can add `onClientClick='return false;'` to the imageButton

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" 
                 ImageUrl="calIcon.jpg" 
                 OnClientClick="return false;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Drag and place Script manager at top of the ajax control or at top of the form.

Comment: It is well understood thing do  u know more

Comment: sometimes your browser would not support. so download the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

As you said that ajax calender works fine on local but when you uploaded it it started creating problems following are the workarounds give them a try.

1. Check that whether you uploaded the ajax toolkit dll on  the server or not.
2. secondly make sure that you uploaded updated web.config file.

   let me know if its helpful otherwise i will try finding other workarounds